# Realm Mobile Platform making a general realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

i'm making an app where users need to register and login, and i'm using RMP. But other than username I need to store some more user data, and for that I have User() objects. I want to save these User() objects into an users realm.

The problem is when creating sync realm, it asks for user. But I don't want to create different realms for different users for each User() object. I want one realm that stores all User() objects. I hope I'm clear. How can I do that? thanks!

Comment: @Tomm if you understand "make me this app" from my question, SO is not a place for you neither.

Comment: @Tomm i'm asking how to make that realm? If you dont know the answer, please dont flood here.

Comment: Well what is wrong when adding a new object from User to realm? I thought is was something like let user = User(), open write block from realm, and between that do realm.add(user).

Comment: @J.Doe when using Mobile Platform, you need to open synced realm to sync between all devices, and while opening synced realm, it needs a user. Then the realm belongs to that user. I dont want all users to have seperate realms for themselves. I want to have one realm and all User() to be stored in it.

Comment: I think all you need to do for that is not have the `/~/` as part of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

To share single Realm with multiple users, there are three ways for now:

1) Share an account. For example, create a system shared account automatically and use it.
2) Use admin account. Admin can create a Realm in global area. `e.g. realm://100.100.100.100/shared`
3) This is similar to 1). Change the permissions of the Realm file and share it among users.

Comment: About number 2, when i create a realm in global area, it says “no access” in default permissions. Does that mean noone can read from this realm?

Comment: To create synced Realm in global area, needs admin account. You need to log in using admin token.

Comment: Yeah i already logged in and created the realm (i logged in with username and password though through code) but the problem is i guess noone else except admin can read from that realm?

Comment: Oh i see. If you’d like to read it from other users, grant appropriate permissions to it

Comment: But I think it is enough using two users at once (admin and the user)

Comment: But its too counter intuative to always chanhe user, when i need that database i need to login with admin, then i need to logout and login with the normal user? That seeems not a good way. Or realm permits to stay logged in with multiple users?

Comment: Yes. realm permits to stay logged in with multiple users.